# Android In App Billing to OpenIAB migration

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I publish app on google play with in-app purchase,i want to publish app on different stores,for that i am using OpenIAB , but unable to understand the official document of OpenIAB, please help me with following points
1. is i have to create in app purchase item with same SKU on every store?
2. line of code that i need to change to replace google IAB to OpenIAB ?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you can map the SKUs if they are different for the supported stores like this:

> ```
> OpenIabHelper.mapSku(SKU_PREMIUM, OpenIabHelper.NAME_GOOGLE,
> "org.onepf.trivialdrive.gp.premium");
> OpenIabHelper.mapSku(SKU_GAS, OpenIabHelper.NAME_GOOGLE,
> "org.onepf.trivialdrive.gp.gas");
> OpenIabHelper.mapSku(SKU_INFINITE_GAS, OpenIabHelper.NAME_GOOGLE,
> "org.onepf.trivialdrive.gp.infinite_gas");
> ```

2. All you have to change in your code can be found [here](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/wiki/Google-Play#in-the-code).